# Count Data each days

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i'm trying to write a query that will give me the result of Count of duration greater than 10 each employee per day.

sapmle data

```
EVENTID     USERID      DATE_TIME   READERID        READERNAME  LOGTYPE USERNAME    RESULT  DURATION

188110074       50078       2020-03-02 22:01:31 544381441       LOCKER      IN   SUBIA, MAY     00:12   12
188099752       50078       2020-03-02 21:48:52 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  SUBIA, MAY             
188098672       50078       2020-03-02 21:47:10 544381441       LOCKER      IN   SUBIA, MAY             
188098656       50078       2020-03-02 21:47:06 544381441       LOCKER      IN   SUBIA, MAY     15:45   945
187972279       50078       2020-03-02 06:01:54 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  SUBIA, MAY             
187949027       50078       2020-03-02 04:30:46 544381441       LOCKER      IN   SUBIA, MAY     00:16   16
187933475       50078       2020-03-01 22:44:47 544381431       LOCKER      IN   SUBIA, MAY     00:04   4
187933289       50078       2020-03-01 22:40:41 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  SUBIA, MAY             
187926256       50078       2020-03-01 22:01:31 544381431       LOCKER      IN   SUBIA, MAY     00:14   14
187914503       50078       2020-03-01 21:46:42 544381428       LOCKER      OUT  SUBIA, MAY 
180769437       1214201592  2020-01-20 08:13:06 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  ALLAN YAP          
180771730       1214201592  2020-01-20 08:36:38 544381431       LOCKER      IN   ALLAN YAP  00:23   23
180775099       1214201592  2020-01-20 09:07:04 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  ALLAN YAP          
180777340       1214201592  2020-01-20 09:30:53 544381431       LOCKER      IN   ALLAN YAP  00:23   23
180778948       1214201592  2020-01-20 09:48:58 544381436       LOCKER      OUT  ALLAN YAP          
180781714       1214201592  2020-01-20 10:04:52 544381431       LOCKER      IN   ALLAN YAP  00:15   15
```

Expected output

```
USERID      DATE_TIME   Count
50078       2020-03-02  3
50078       2020-03-01  1
1214201592  2020-01-20  3
```

Here's what i have tried

```
Select count, USERNAME,  DATE_TIME
from (
Select  A.USERNAME,A.DATE_TIME , Count(A.Duration) count
from TBLACCESSLOGS A    
where Duration > 10 
Group by Date_Time,USERNAME)
```

Note: Date_time is in varchar type
but got wrong result , its looks like far from what i expected.

Hope someone help me out with this

Comment: Please check this `Select count, USERNAME,  DATE_TIME
from (
Select  A.USERNAME,CAST(A.DATE_TIME AS DATE) DATE_TIME , Count(A.Duration) count
from TBLACCESSLOGS A    
where Duration > 10 
Group by CAST(A.DATE_TIME AS DATE),USERNAME)`

Comment: iteral does not match format string
pointing at the date_time, i forgot to say the Date_time is a varchar data type

Comment: Ok, no problem :)

Comment: Can you check this `DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(30) ='2020-03-02 22:01:31';

SELECT CAST(@DATE AS DATE)
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@DATE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite closer to your expected output. Just use TRUNC as following:

```
SELECT
    A.USERNAME,
    A.USERID, -- this
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(A.DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS DATE_TIME,
    COUNT(A.DURATION) COUNT
FROM
    TBLACCESSLOGS A
WHERE
    DURATION > 10
GROUP BY
    A.USERNAME,
    A.USERID, -- this
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(A.DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Cheers!!

Comment: trunc is not working because the Date_time is in Varchar2 data type

Comment: question how can i include userID i tried this `SELECT
    A.USERNAME,
    A.USERID,
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(A.DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS DATE_TIME,
    COUNT(A.DURATION) COUNT
FROM
    TBLACCESSLOGS A

WHERE
    A.DURATION > 45 
       -- A.DURATION > 10 and D.ISRESTDAY <> 1 and  TRUNC(TO_DATE(A.DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) = trunc(sysdate-1)
GROUP BY
    USERNAME,
    USERID,
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(A.DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))`

Comment: as i join it in other table the query take 10min to excute and returns only 1 day per user, `SELECT
    A.USERNAME,
    A.USERID, -- this
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(A.DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) AS DATE_TIME,
    COUNT(A.DURATION) COUNT
FROM
    TBLACCESSLOGS A
    inner join TBLEMPLOYEEGROUP B
on Lpad(A.USERID,'6','0') = B.EMPLOYEEID
inner join TBLSHIFTGROUP C
on B.GROUPCODE = C.GROUPCODE
inner join TBLSHIFTROTATESCHED D
on C.SHIFTCODE = D.SHIFTCODE 
WHERE
    DURATION > 45
GROUP BY
    A.USERNAME,
    A.USERID, -- this
    TRUNC(TO_DATE(A.DATE_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))`

Comment: ca you help me [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501635/count-data-each-shift-schedule]

Answer (score 1):

Please check this it's work for me.

Note you need to check this.

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(30) ='2020-03-02 22:01:31'; 
SELECT CAST(@DATE AS DATE) SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@DATE)

SELECT
    A.USERNAME,
    CAST(A.DATE_TIME AS DATE) AS DATE_TIME,
    COUNT(A.DURATION) TotalCount
FROM
    TBLACCESSLOGS A
WHERE
    DURATION > 10
GROUP BY
    USERNAME,
    CAST(A.DATE_TIME AS DATE)
```

> 2. Another way

```
SELECT
    A.USERNAME,
    CONVERT(DATE,A.DATE_TIME) AS DATE_TIME,
    COUNT(A.DURATION) TotalCount
FROM
    TBLACCESSLOGS A
WHERE
    DURATION > 10
GROUP BY
    USERNAME,
    CONVERT(DATE,A.DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: would you help me out with this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501635/countdata-each-shift-schedule]

Comment: Ok, brother let me check.